# How to determine if the last shutdown was due to power failure in windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

I know I can get logs of shutdowns from the eventlog when the shutdown is proper and initiated by the user or due to software upgrades. But how do I determine if the last shutdown was due power failure, over heating etc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `System` event log, look for EventID 41 Kernel-Power. It's description is:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

That sounds like what you're looking for, correct?

Comment: Also if the system was shut down cleanly there will allways be 3 events "Event Log" in a row. One stopping one stopped and one starting.

Comment: Is there any way to know when the last shutdown happened due to the reasons mentioned in my question?

Comment: You can have a scheduled task with that event as a trigger and have it send an email or do whatever else you want.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a service and maybe do a "touch" on a file every n minutes and then compare its last modified date with the event timestamp to figure this out. Do you think this will be efficient or do you have any better way?

Comment: Why do you need that, there's a time listed with the event...

Comment: If the machine got shutdown because of a power failure, I don't think any event will be generated. Then how will I know when the shutdown happened? And it may be hours before the machine is turned on again. This machine will be run in a place where power is very erratic. I need both the boot time and shutdown(for any reason) time for a report.

Comment: You mean in case of power failure a event is generated, can you please explain as to how can I dig this out? I checked eventid 41, only bootup time is present, not when the shutdown happened.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom event viewer view of the System log and restrict the source to

> Source: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power

These should notify you about power-loss and subsequent power-restored events.